# What tool do I need to remove a round nut with slots in its face?

Tags: tools, screwdriver

The crank shaft and axle are a single unit, so the whole thing needs to be removed.

Diameter is approx. 50 mm and a spanner/wrench/screwdriver needs to be able to grip both notches and twist without being blocked by the crank arm.

Any suggestions?

[image: Nut is from an exercise bike]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That would call for a [pin wrench](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wrench#Types).

[image]

Comment: But if you don't have a pin spanner wrench, can you loosen it by placing a screwdriver in one slot at an angle and tapping the end with a hammer?

Comment: @JimStewart if you are lucky and it’s not too tight, but it’s also easy to damage that ring...

Comment: Yeah, the screwdriver approach can work but it is a recipe for frustration. It's harder than it sounds to get enough force in the right direction to move what may be a tight and stuck piece.

Comment: Thanks all for the tips. I tried the screwdriver approach in the first instance, but as @isherwood suspected, this was a road to frustration. Currently waiting on my pin wrench to arrive in the mail.